# Upper bound on the Lambert function

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods, lambert-w

Is there an upper bound on the Lambert function $$W(-\frac{k}{e})$$ for $0 < k < 1$? Or should the condition be $0 < k \leq 1$?

I know that $W(-\frac{1}{e}) = -1$; would it be okay to say $W(-\frac{k}{e}) \leq -1$?

I just recently learned about Lambert functions and am having a hard time understanding all these. This came from an approximation of an expression given by:

$$\ln \phi_\infty = \mu + \lambda \phi_\infty - \mu e^{-\lambda \phi_\infty},$$

which by letting $z=\lambda \phi_\infty$, yields
$$z = -\frac{1}{1+\mu}W(-\lambda(1+\mu))$$
which only exists if
$$\lambda (1+\mu) \leq \frac{1}{e}.$$
If we let $\lambda = ke^{-1}\frac{1}{1+\mu}$ for $0 < k \leq 1$, we can have
$$ z = -\frac{1}{1+\mu}W\bigg(-\frac{k}{e}\bigg). $$

What I need is to represent this last equation in terms of $\phi_\infty$ alone (and these parameters $\lambda, \mu$) so I was wondering if I could get an upper bound for the Lambert function and do just that.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: The red curve on https://dlmf.nist.gov/4.13 shows it is not OK.

Comment: Assuming no disingenuousness here, please share your motivation.

Comment: @Aruralreader have edited the post and added the process for arriving at this question :)

Comment: Which branch do you denote by $W$? The answer depends on that.

Comment: @Gary I believe this is for the general Lambert function for either the principal branch $W_0$ or $W_1$. Sorry for the confusion, I am not sure about it yet myself.

Comment: Take care :the expression you give for $z$ is **not** the solution of the equation. It is the simplest first estimate I found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$W$ without a subscript usually means $W_0$.

Let $f(k)=W\left(-\frac{k}{e}\right)$ for $0<k<1$.

See Wolfram Alpha for [the graph of $f$, extended by the points $(0,0)$ and $(1,-1)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+W%280%2C-k%2Fe%29%2Ck%3D0+to+1).

$$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0,\ \ \lim_{x\to 1}f(x)=-1$$

See at Wikipedia: [Upper and lower bounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_and_lower_bounds), [Bounded function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_function) and [Bounded set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_set).

$f$ is a bounded function: bounded above by $0$ and bounded below by $-1$.

$$-1<f(k)<0$$